# Using DHT11 and EMF - Lag issue

Tags: arduino-nano

The code is working but there is a delay when the LED turns on and off (physically). Is there a more efficient way I could write this code? I assume it is the delay in reading the DHT11 causing it.

~Issue resolved

Comment: Don't have a delay?

Comment: there is one, physically, when the LED lights up and turns off.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "physically", but there is a delay in your code. Remove it, and if you need parts of your code to run slower, use `millis()` to determine when they should run.

Comment: Please leave the original question intact so others can benefit from your question and its solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear (A delay is defined by two points in time or one point and a duration -- you only tell us one point).

Reading your code, I can only assume that you mean that an external event on `inPin` is delayed in showing up on the LED on `pin11`. This should come up when that external event is emitted just at the beginning of your `delay(1000)` (and is therefore randomly delayed between 0 and 1000ms).

You could get rid of the delay in your loop using a bit of timer math around the DHT11 reading code:

```
#define DHT11_SAMPLE_DELAY = 1000
uint32_t last_dht11_reading_ms = 0;

void loop() {
  uint32_t current_ms = millis();

  if( current_ms - last_dht11_reading_ms > DHT11_SAMPLE_DELAY ) {

    DHT.read11(dht_apin);
    Serial.println("....your output....");

    last_dht11_reading_ms = current_ms;
  }
  // also, remove the delay(1000) in your loop()
}
```

You get the current time (`millis()` gives you the uptime since boot in milliseconds) and subtract the time of last reading. If the result is bigger than a threshold (in this case: 1000 ms), you do a new reading of the DHT11 while setting the variable containing the time of last reading to the current time. When the `loop()` comes around again, the threshold will not be reached, so reading the DHT11 value is skipped until `millis()` returns a sufficiently big number again.

Comment: @RobE If you did copy my error in the `DHT.read11()` call, then I can see why... if you didn't, I'd be very surprised ^^ (Fixed the errorneous call. It should be the same line as in your original code.)

Comment: Updated the code, now the temp sensor never reads. I must have done something wrong. I updated the code above in the OP.

Comment: @RobE Nice to see that your issue has been resolved, but could you please leave the question here so others can find the solution? The intended way here on Stackoverflow is to keep everything readable, so others won't have to ask the same question again. Instead of removing the question, please mark an answer as correct.